# MPMoviePlayerController play video starting from 30th sec (from mid of the video)

Tags: ios, objective-c, position, mpmovieplayercontroller, playback

I am creating a simple media player using `MPMoviePlayerController`, here I want to play the videos from particular point like from 30th sec or 50th second onwards and also want to move the video player head to any particular point and start playing it from that point. I tried with `initialPlaybackTime` and `MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward` but no luck.

video is not from local, its from server.

Please help me to do the same.

Answer (score 14):

```
MPMoviePlayerController *mp;

mp.initialPlaybackTime = 84;
mp.endPlaybackTime = 118;
```

It will start movie playback from 84th second till the 118th second.