# Play 3 sec section from the whole video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I have a 10 sec length video clip and I want to play it from 3 sec to 6 sec. Is this possible with CCPlayer? Or even MPMoviewPlayer?

This is my code:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *_theMovie;  
[_theMovie setCurrentPlaybackTime:1.0];  
[_theMovie setEndPlaybackTime:2.0];  
[_theMovie play];
```

But video plays from 0 to 2 sec :(

Thanks

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439958/mpmovieplayercontroller-play-video-starting-from-30th-sec-from-mid-of-the-video

Comment: thanks for ur reply, but i've tried that already. nothing heppens : (

Comment: any news? can any1 tell me more info ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the two setters in docs.

```
// The start time of movie playback. Defaults to NaN, indicating the natural start time of the movie.
@property(nonatomic) NSTimeInterval initialPlaybackTime;

// The end time of movie playback. Defaults to NaN, which indicates natural end time of the movie.
@property(nonatomic) NSTimeInterval endPlaybackTime;


MPMoviePlayerController *_theMovie;
[theMovie setInitialPlaybackTime:3.0]; //instead of [_theMovie setCurrentPlaybackTime:1.0];
[theMovie setEndPlaybackTime:6.0];
[_theMovie prepareToPlay];
[_theMovie play];
```

:)

Comment: and why i need to set the properties?

Comment: @Rendel, glad to know that! Happie coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

change the currentPlaybackRate time in MPMoviewPlayer,

```
moviplayer.currentPlaybackRate =moviePlayer.duration/3 or  6;
```