# Android MediaPlayer setDataSource iOS alternative

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, media-player, avfoundation

I have android implementation which sets media player **data source range** between 10000 **bytes** and 40000000 **bytes**:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "path to video file");
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD(),1000,40000000);
```

Is there any alternative to do the same in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set the range based on bytes in iOS. But you can specify the video's playback range based on time. An example is given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439958/mpmovieplayercontroller-play-video-starting-from-30th-sec-from-mid-of-the-video).

Comment: I'm not interested in time, I need bytes offset. Do am I talking about time in question description?

Comment: Is there a way you can know the data source size? If so, probably you can try calculating the time range proportionate to the data range you want it to be implemented for. I am not sure how accurate it will be but you can give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate it manually by the combination of the two:

// 1 Get AVAsset file size
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:URL error:&attributesError];

NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
long long fileSize = [fileSizeNumber longLongValue];

// 2 now from the estimated data rate
Get [Estimated data rate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetTrack_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAssetTrack/estimatedDataRate)

so now you can have the CMTime and you can pass it accordingly.
Hope this helps.

Comment: CMTime gives me time offset, not bytes offset. So I think it's not the solution.

Comment: As i mentioned you have to dynamically calculate the memory bytes offset every time by means of the estimateddatarate and pass it in the segmenttracktime. Since , time is more precise than data offset in the sandbox environment Apple prefers it.